# Angular Application not loading through Docker

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I have an Angular application that runs perfectly fine when I do `ng serve` from the command line. However, when I put the application in a Docker container and attempt to run the container, I get this error in the DOM(just an excerpt):

```
  Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h2>Register new User</h2>
        <form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group">
            "): ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@5:14
     No provider for ControlContainer ("
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h2>Register new User</h2>
        [ERROR ->]<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group">
      "): ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@5:8
    No provider for NgControl ("
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            [ERROR ->]<input type="text" formControlName="firstName" 
    class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submit"): ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@8:12
    No provider for NgControl ("
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            [ERROR ->]<input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitt"): ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@15:12
ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@39:12
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at 




    TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22709)
```

My Dockerfile(which is being built in the correct location) is as follows:

```
# Stage 1 Build
FROM node:8.11.3
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH ./node_modules/bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

#Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY dist/ .
```

Many of the solutions I have researched thus far have involved making changes to the `app.module.ts` file that allow `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`to be imported and exported:

```
 exports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
 imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
HttpModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
CommonModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

But I still have not been able to get this working through Docker. Has anyone encountered this issue in the past?

Comment: Just a guess here, but don't some angular packages you install already require the angular cli?
What I'm getting at: maybe try installing the angular cli before you do npm install

Comment: I switched the two RUN npm install instructions, so that the angular cli one goes first. But it seems to yield the same result. Much appreciated though, didn't even consider that.

Comment: Another odd thought: The dockerfile 'RUN' commands are not necessarily executing in the order you expect them as they might get cached.
So maybe a single 'RUN' with the commands concatenated with '&&' could help.

Comment: So something like "RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8 &&  npm install"?

Comment: Almost, leave out the second 'RUN':
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8 && npm install
or if you want it more readable:
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8 \
(new line here)npm install

Comment: Still seeing the same errors :(